# >Calculate the volume of the $n$-dimensional ball using change of variables.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, change-of-variable

> Calculate the volume of the $n$-dimensional ball using change of variables.

**My attempt.**

> **Lemma 1.** For each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have
>   $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{k}xdx = \frac{k-1}{k}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{k-2}xdx.$$

*Proof.* Done.

> **Corollary.** If $k$ is even, then
>   $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{k}xdx = \left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)\left(\frac{k-3}{k-2}\right)\cdots\frac{3}{4}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^2xdx,$$
>   $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{k-1}xdx = \left(\frac{k-2}{k-1}\right)\left(\frac{k-4}{k-3}\right)\cdots\frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin xdx.$$
>   Moreover,
>   $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{k}xdx\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{k-1}xdx = \frac{2\pi}{k}.$$

*Proof.* Done.

Thus, if $k$ is even, take $I_{k} = \int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{k}xdx$, we have
$$I_{k}I_{k-1}\cdots I_{1} = (I_{k}I_{k-1})\cdots (I_{2}I_{1}) = \frac{(2\pi)^{\frac{k}{2}}}{k(k-2)\cdots 2}.$$
Analogously, if $k$ is odd,
$$I_{k}I_{k-1}\cdots I_{1} = (I_{k}I_{k-1})\cdots (I_{3}I_{2})I_{1} = \frac{2(2\pi)^{\frac{k-1}{2}}}{k(k-2)\cdots 3}.$$

Now,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathrm{vol}(B_{R}) & = & \int_{B_{R}}dx\\
& = & \int_{(0,R)\times(0,\pi)^{n-2}\times(0,\pi)}r^{n-1}\sin_{n-2}(\theta_{1})\cdots\sin(\theta_{n-1})drd\theta_{1}...d\theta_{n-1}d\theta_{n}\\
& \underbrace{=}_{\color{red}{\mathrm{Fubini}}} & \int_{0}^{R}r^{n-1}dr\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta_{n}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{n-2}(\theta_{1})d\theta_{n-1}\cdots\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(\theta_{n-1})d\theta_{n-1}\\
& = & 2\pi\frac{R^{n}}{n}I_{n-2}I_{n-3}\cdots I_{1}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

By previous comments,
$$I_{n-2}I_{n-3}\cdots I_{1} = \frac{(2\pi)^{\frac{n-2}{2}}}{(n-2)\cdots 2}$$
if $n$ is even, and
$$I_{n-2}I_{n-3}\cdots I_{1} = \frac{2(2\pi)^{\frac{n-3}{2}}}{(n-2)\cdots 3}$$
if $n$ is odd.

Therefore,
$$\mathrm{vol}(B_{R}) = \begin{cases} 2\pi\frac{R^{n}}{n}\frac{(2\pi)^{\frac{n-2}{2}}}{(n-2)\cdots 2}& \text{if }n\text{ is even} \\ 2\pi\frac{R^{n}}{n}\frac{2(2\pi)^{\frac{n-3}{2}}}{(n-2)\cdots 3}& \text{if }n\text{ is odd}\end{cases},$$
that is,
$$\mathrm{vol}(B_{R}) = \begin{cases} \frac{(2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}R^{n}}{n(n-2)\cdots 2}& \text{if }n\text{ is even} \\ \frac{2(2\pi)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}R^{n}}{n(n-2)\cdots 3}& \text{if }n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}.$$

Is this correct? Testing for $n = 3$, is right. I think that the final result is right, but I'm not sure about all the details in the last part.